# How to Expire Session IDs in Cookies for Active Admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activeadmin

I'm facing an issue with the session management in my web application. I've noticed that the session ID stored in a cookie doesn't seem to expire, which poses a security risk. If someone obtains this session ID, they can potentially log in to Active Admin.

I'm using Ruby on Rails with the Active Admin gem for my application.

My questions are:

Why isn't the session ID expiring as expected?
How can I force the session ID to expire after a certain period of inactivity?
Are there any additional security measures I should consider to prevent unauthorized access to Active Admin?
I appreciate any guidance or solutions to help me address this issue and improve the security of my application. Thank you in advance!

Comment: As far as I know, ActiveAdmin doesn't include authorization, but instead it uses the authentication system of the main application, which might be using the Devise gem, another authentication gem or something you wrote on your own. Therefore: How did you implement authentication in your application in the first place?

Comment: Note that authentication which is for example provided by Devise is a higher level concept built on the low level functionality provided by the Rails session middleware. The session middleware concept of a session is just a simple data store that persists across requests. It should not be equated with logging in / out. You can configure the expiry for the session storage cookies but if you want to implement timeouts properly you want something like Devise::Timeoutable.

Comment: With Devise, I have a cookie called '_session_id' that never expires. The only way to achieve this is by using Devise:Timeoutable, correct?